# How to get product collection form brand_id in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Basically i want to get product collection form brand_id.is there anyway to get collection.

Comment: Is brand_id product attribute ?

Comment: basically when we add product we select band and add product in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the product collection by attribute code and their selected value in Magento 2.

I'm writing a block class `BrandProducts` method to achieve your requirement.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class BrandProducts extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $attributeSelectionId = 28; //for example 28 is attribute value of your attribute selection
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('your_attribute_code', $attributeSelectionId);
        $collection->setPageSize(3); // fetching only 3 products
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

**Hope it helps you to find your solution.**

Comment: Have you tried it @usman?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply .I have not tried it because i find other solution.

Comment: OK, perfect....